# print an array with layout param

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am trying to print a shared preference into a text view , the problem is when i am trying to save a new one it overrides on the previus.
i need help to make them being and array an not overriding time of time.

```
public void loadPicture()
{
    //this is how i load the sharedpreferences on another page.
    gallery.removeAllViews();
    List<String> array =fetchAllPreference();
    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
    {
        TextView iv = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,0,0);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setText(array.get(i));
        gallery.addView(iv);
    }
}
    //how i save the sharedpreferences
    sendnewword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
            getSharedPreferences("DictionaryInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("Herbew", Hebrew.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("English", English.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();
            Intent B = new Intent(New_words.this, All_words.class);
            startActivity(B);

        }
    });

//making all sharedpreferences to an array.
public List<String> fetchAllPreference(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("DictionaryInfo", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    int index = 0;
    Map<String,?> allPrefs = sharedPref.getAll();
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : allPrefs.entrySet()){
        values.add(entry.getValue().toString());
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Create JSONArray and add JSONObject in this array. like

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("book_name", "English");
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        // you can create multiple jsonObject and then add it to jsonArray
        array.put(jsonObject);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("books", array.toString());
        editor.apply();

        // now get array of objects from shared Pref.

        String  data =fetchAllPreference();
        JSONArray fetchedData = new JSONArray(data);

        for(int i=0;i<fetchedData.length();i++)
        {
            TextView iv = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
            layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,0,0);
            iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            // put id to everyview
            iv.setId(i);
            iv.setText(fetchedData.getJSONObject(i).getString("book_name"));
            gallery.addView(iv);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Enjoy

Comment: but still even with json not working , only one and delete it again.

Comment: What is gallery ? Its a linearlayout or relativelayout ? or framelayout ? gallery should linearlayout and its orientation should vertical or horizontal. please confirm this

Comment: linear layout yes , i cant use it like this because i did it in another activitys, what should i do

Comment: + fetchallpreferences return a list not a  string , code is not working for me.

Comment: to get all string from fetchallprefrences use this code `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.getString("books", null);
        editor.commit();` in your fetchallpreferences

Comment: i cant get it :(

Comment: can you please make it in the original functions?

Comment: your code is working fine. please check your gallery layout. or set its orientation